# After installing Angular Google Maps (AGM) Application throws a list of exceptions

Tags: html, css, angular, google-maps, typescript

I have installed Angular Google Maps (**AGM**) after installing that module application throws a list of exceptions, before it was working fine.

- node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,43): error 
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
- node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,22): error
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
- node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Comment: Did you install the @types for the library, too?

Comment: Just installed still no luck!